# Qué esta mal en este filtro por selección en angular+9

Tags: angular, typescript, date, select, filtro

Buen día, tengo problemas con un filtro ya que no me filtra x fecha, pero si filtro por otro dato funciona muy bien, necesitaría de su ayuda, no se que estoy haciendo mal. Gracias.

**HTML**

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="seleccion" (ngModelChange)="selection(seleccion)">
         <option *ngFor="let p productos" 
               [value]="p.fecha.toDate() | date:'shortDate'"> 
                  {{p.fecha.toDate() | date:'shortDate' }}
        </option>
  </select>

 <table >
    <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Fecha</th> 
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let i of data;">
         <td> {{item.fecha.toDate() | date:'shortDate' }} </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**TS**

```
seleccion;
data;

selection(v) {  
    this.data = this.productos.filter(x =>
        x.fecha.toDate() == v

    )
} 

constructor()  {
      this.data = this.productos;
}
```

Comment: Sin saber los datos que estás usado, está complicado

Comment: mmm los datos provienen de firebase de una coleccion.

Comment: pero si por ejemplo busco por p.name ya ahi funciona de maravilla, los datos del atributo fecha estan guardados tipo TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si fecha es de la clase [`Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp), entonces el método `toDate` devuelve un objeto Date. No puedes comparar objetos en Javascript/Typescript con == porque eso es comprobar que el objeto es la misma instancia:

```js
let date1 = new Date(1620136919551);
// misma fecha exacta para ambos
let date2 = new Date(1620136919551);

console.log("date 1", date1.toString());
console.log("date 2", date2.toString());

console.log("Son el mismo?", date1 == date2);

//comparación de valores

console.log("son iguales?", date1.getTime() === date2.getTime())
```